# send and receive data from Activity class to Fragment class on eclipse Android

Tags: android

when you lunch my app , the app show you MM - Fragment class - .
After that , you should go to another by lift menu (like Milk) .then you will press button for sending data -one int and two string - and going to Activity class - its name Add - ,this is code :

```
mil001add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener (){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent a = new Intent("android.intent.action.add");
            a.putExtra("milkcal", Content.Mil001.calory);
            a.putExtra("milkcon", Content.Mil001.consist);
            a.putExtra("milkmea", Content.Mil001.meal);
            startActivity(a);


        }});
```

Add receive and change data - i will not wright code of change data - by this code :

```
Intent n = this.getIntent();
nam =n.getExtras().getString("milkmea");
con = n.getExtras().getString("milkcon");
cal =n.getExtras().getInt("milkcal");
```

Until now app work very good , problem is i can't send data from Add to MM .
i hope to find solution.

Comment: Do you mean return result from the second activity to the first one?

Comment: I see your intent is  Intent a = new Intent("android.intent.action.add");.Not clear about this intent "android.intent.action.add" is class name.

Comment: Intent a = new Intent("android.intent.action.add");   i send data from milk (fragment ) to add (activity class ) . That work well . but i cant send from add to mm (fragment )

Answer (score 0):

If you want you will send the data from any fragment class to activity you can use this.

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,
                    FoodSelectionActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", mProduct.getTitle().toString().trim());
            intent.putExtra("productid", (Integer) mProduct.getProductid());
            intent.putExtra("restaurantId", restaurantId);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Where FoodSelectionActivity.class is Activity.
Now you can receive this data from this way

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        titleString = bundle.getString("title");
        productid = bundle.getInt("productid");
        restaurantId = bundle.getString("restaurantId");

    }
```

It working on my application.

Comment: My problem is , I cant send from activity to fragment

Comment: Up up up up up up up

Answer (score 0):

Create this interface in your fragment class. Name it whatever you want. You would need to change the method parameters to something that you need to get. It could be anything.

```
  /**
         * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
         * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
         * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
         * activity.
         * <p/>
         * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
         * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
         * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
         */
        public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
            // TODO: Update argument type and name
            public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
        }
```

After that you implement this interface in your activity.

Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentName.OnFragmentInteractionListener
```

Then you override the methods, in this case ***onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri)***

You call *onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri)* in the fragment and the data you specified in the parameters, in this case a Uri object will be available to the activity.